# Cut text in iPhone simulator with UIRoundRectButton- unlike what I see in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am creating a simple calculator app, following the tutorials from Stanford - [first assignment](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall).

The actual content is not that relevant, the only issue is that I have a UIRoundRectButton in the storyboard, which displays a fixed text (like "sqrt").
When I run it in the simulator (iPhone 5, iOS 6) - the text in SOME of the buttons gets cut off.

Screenshots:

[image] [image]

Any help?

Comment: check your view structure, you button are getting override by some view..

Comment: You can also generally fix this by just remaking the buttons.

Comment: I did no change to the view structure... Normal round rect buttons straight from the SDK (drag-drop from object explorer).

Comment: Tried recreating the buttons (Max's comment) - it fixed the lower 4 buttons and it screwed up the buttons above them. Holy crap =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're designing on a 4 inch xib but running on the 3.5 inch simulator, Autolayout will be pinning your lower buttons to the bottom of the screen and they will be getting squashed. Try one of:

- Running on the 4 inch simulator (device--> hardware menu)
- Switch to 3.5inch view in the storyboard (the grey icon on the bottom with the triangles above and below it
- turning off Autolayout (on the file inspector of the storyboard)
- Defining your constraints properly so they are all relative to the top of the view.

Those tutorials were written before Autolayout and the 4 inch display. You probably just want to focus on the tutorial content at this stage, so the last option is probably too much, but I have a blog post [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/18/autolayout-in-interface-builder/) discussing editing constraints in IB.

Comment: Turning off Autolayout solved it - thanks. The blog post is helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Please uncheck "Use Autolayout" option under "Show the file inspector" for XIB.